# Можно ли удалить использованные primery key в postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть БД, где в колонке id(primery key) автоматически нумеруются записи. Но проблема в том, что если, к примеру, удалить одну из записей, то автоматически созданный id, который у неё был, уже нельзя будет использовать для другой записи. В итоге, как видно на картинке, всего у меня столбцов 6, а id уже дошёл до 21. Можно ли это как-то исправить и вернуть нумерацию в порядок?

Comment: А тебе вообще `id` нужен в этой таблице? Судя по тому, как ты их хочешь туда-сюда менять, может он тебе вообще здесь не нужен?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, ```id``` указывал на номер документа в url. Чтоб если захотел быстро перейти к документу, можно было это сделать с помощью изменения в url /id. А так, когда номера в разнобой, сложно будет таким заниматься. 
*На возможный вопрос, почему не создал отдельную колонку для нумерации url - потому, что думал, что id можно будет поправить при его разнобое.
Но, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: o_O Да, когда ты начнёшь ИД тасовать, переход к документу по номеру ИД станет куда проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главный вопрос 'А зачем?'...смысл pk чтоб он не повторялся в прошлом и не пересекался в будущем.

Если нужны номера строк, то они формируются при выборке - на картинке левее.

Но если хочется.... то можно. В постгресе эти номера строятся на основе уникального индекса и внешнего счётчика как значение по умолчанию. Раскрой те схему таблицы и посмотрите имя счётчика. Или командой

```
pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name','column_name')
```

И отвечая на вопрос

```
ALTER SEQUENCE pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name','id') RESTART WITH 3;
```

Что конечно убьёт производительность новых вставок так как надо будет перед каждой вставкой проверять ограничение уникальности вручную.

Comment: "И отвечая на вопрос ...RESTART WITH 3;" ага, целых 11 ключей будет работать.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov проведи эксперимент, может саморесетнится на 15

Comment: не саморесетнится)

Comment: На производительность записи не повлияет никак. Сказали сиквенсу считать с такого-то значения - он и будет возвращать значения отсюда. А то что у вас часть insert'ов откатятся с ошибкой из-за нарушения уникальности PK - это не проблема сиквенса, а того, кто запросил такой alter sequence. (никакой выделенной предварительной проверки уникальности нет, новое значений сиквенса при конфликте тоже никто запрашивать не будет. Данные новой строки нам всё равно нужно записать в индексы - вот там непосредственности при записи в btree и обрабатывается конфликт уникальности)

Comment: @Мелкий поскольку инсерты будут отваливаться нужно их будет повторить

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли это как-то исправить и вернуть нумерацию в порядок?

Забудьте об этом. И вообще никогда не пускайте такую мысль себе в голову.

Первичный ключ - это специальная конструкция в структуре таблицы. Единственным её назначением является уникальная идентификация записи в течение всего срока существования таблицы. Обращаю особое внимание - именно таблицы, а не самой записи! То есть даже если запись была удалена, её уже нет, но тем не менее значение первичного ключа, которое у неё было, указывает на эту несуществующую сейчас запись. Да, необычная концепция, но её нужно и принять, и осознать.

Вообще первичный ключ - это чисто внутреннее дело сервера. И в нормальных условиях получение/просмотр его значения нужен в одном-единственном случае - если нужно убедиться, что значению первичного ключа не грозит переполнение.

Любая попытка возложить на значение первичного ключа какую-то дополнительную функцию - это плохо. Надо ли говорить, что если нечто выполняет несколько разных функций, то все их оно выполняет плохо. Или во всяком случае хуже, если бы каждая функция выполнялась отдельным, специально предназначенным только для этой функции, чем-то.

Нужна непрерывная нумерация? создайте для неё отдельное поле, и заботьтесь о том, чтобы в нём не было "дырок".

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение!